# Maximum number of Full HD 1920x1080 displays supported on Macbook Pro 15" 2016 and later?

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt, displayport

Is there a limit to how many Full HD 1920x1080 displays are supported on the 15" Macbook Pro 2016 and later? If a single USB-C port can currently give you up to 2 video outputs either through a TB3 hub or through a USB-C to dual displayport adapter (daisy-chaining currently not supported) would it be possible to connect 8 Full HD 1920x1080 displays? Or is there a limit to 4 displays in general? The Macbook Pro runs with an AMD Radeon processors most of which have the Eyefinite Technology which gives you up to 6 displays. Does that also work with Macbook Pro 15" 2016 and later?

Answer (score 1):

The technical specifications page on Apple's website provides this information.  For the 2016 MacBook Pro:

Video Support

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
>   at millions of colors and:
>
> - Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors

> The Macbook Pro runs with an AMD Radeon processors most of which have
>   the Eyefinite Technology which gives you up to 6 displays.

Just because a chip is *capable* of doing something, doesn't mean it was enabled by Apple.  Case in point - daisy chaining.  The DisplayPort spec 1.2 calls for daisy chaining monitors, but as you have found out, it isn't supported.

As for later Macs, you would need to check the specifications for each one individually